# AngularJS: Dynamically binding Click in directive gets fired multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to add fields dynamically and I'm binding `click` event in the directive's `link` function. But it seems to be firing several times as I add more fields. See the example below -

```js
var clicks = 0;
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.directive('control', function($compile) {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html('<button style="background:grey;">Button ' + scope.count + '</button>');

    element.bind('click', function() {
      clicks++;
      $('#clicks').html('Clicked ' + clicks + ' times')
    });

    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      count: '@'
    },
    link: linker
  }
});

app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.count = 1;
  $scope.addControl = function() {
    $('#content').append('<control count="' + $scope.count+++'"></control>');
    $compile($('#content').contents())($scope);
  };
});
```

```css
#content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#clicks {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
p {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="TestController">
  <button ng-click="addControl()">Add Button</button>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="clicks"></div>
</div>

<p>Add multiple buttons and click the button that was added in the beginning. Notice the Clicks to be increased multiple times.</p>
<p>For instance, add a bunch of buttons and click Button 1</p>
```

I'd like to have the `click` event fired only once for a specific element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you are compile `#content` DOM multiple times, Because of that your old elements are again get binded click event to it. If you look closely you will see that you `nth` button is having `n-1` click event binded to it.

Below is explanation.

1. When you add first button it does add it and compile first button.

   - Now `#content` has 1 button, which has 1 click event binded to it.
2. When you add second button, it it getting added in DOM but it recompiling whole `#content` DOM, you know what it was already having 1 button with click event. When you `#content` DOM, it will recompile first directive again and will add click event again to it. Also it will click event to second button.

   - Now `#content` has 2 button
   - 1st button have 2 events bounded to it
   - 2nd button has 1 events bounded to it
3. When you add 3rd button you will see below change

   - Now `#content` has 2 button
   - 1st button have 3 events bounded to it
   - 2nd button have 2 events bounded to it
   - 3rd button has 1 event bounded to it

I'd say that don't render `controls` on form by own by recompiling DOM every time. Suppose you have added are going to 100th control over the page, for that you are recompiling `99` control for no reason, technically which doesn't make sense. So better you should give responsibility of rendering controls to `ng-repeat`.

**Markup**

```
<div ng-controller="TestController">
    <button ng-click="addControl()">Add Button</button>
    <div ng-repeat="control in controls"><control count="{{control}}"></control></div>
    <div id="clicks"></div>
</div>
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.count = 1;
  $scope.controls = [];
  $scope.controlsCount = 0;
  $scope.addControl = function() {
    $scope.controls.push(++$scope.controlsCount);
  };
});
```

[**Demo plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/bG8Kuh3zAhUbwN0cFnOr?p=preview)

Comment: Why my answer didn't get marked/upvoted? Any ideas/suggestions?

Comment: downvoter may I know reason behind downvote it? please do add comment so that I'll come to know whats wrong there, to improve me.

Comment: @MedetTleukabiluly The issue was I was compiling `#content` every single time I created a new control (as pointed out by Pankaj). Even though unbinding works, I don't think that is the actual solution to my problem.

Comment: @AswinRamakrishnan but I don't understand why mine answer get downvote? do you have any idea :(

Answer (score 1):

You are binding `click` event twice, 
[image]
Because directive is initialized twice in link phase, where click handler is binded, you triggered digest cycle by `$compile(element.contents())(scope);` which attached event to directive, because they are in link phase, but events can be binded multiple times, so directive has multiple click events, first suggestion is to `unbind` event first

```
element.unbind('click').bind('click');
```

You may ask how it comes that element may have multiple click events, here's how

```
//event1
document.body.onclick = function(){ console.log('event1'); }

//event2
var oldClick = document.body.onclick;
document.body.onclick = function(){ console.log('event2'); oldClick.bind(document.body).call(); }

//this will trigger
event2
event1
```

[image]

Working sample below

```js
var clicks = 0;
var app = angular.module('test', []);

app.directive('control', function($compile) {
  var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
    element.html('<button style="background:grey;">Button ' + scope.count + '</button>');
    element.unbind('click').bind('click', function() {
      clicks++;
      $('#clicks').html('Clicked ' + clicks + ' times')
    });
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
  };

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      count: '@'
    },
    link: linker
  }
});

app.controller('TestController', function($scope, $compile) {
  $scope.count = 1;
  $scope.addControl = function() {
    $('#content').append('<control count="' + $scope.count+++'"></control>');
    $compile($('#content').contents())($scope);
  };
});
```

```css
#content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
#clicks {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
p {
  color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="test" ng-controller="TestController">
  <button ng-click="addControl()">Add Button</button>
  <div id="content"></div>
  <div id="clicks"></div>
</div>

<p>Add multiple buttons and click the button that was added in the beginning. Notice the Clicks to be increased multiple times.</p>
<p>For instance, add a bunch of buttons and click Button 1</p>
```

Comment: you have only `element.unbind('click').bind('click');` this part is correct..but explanation is not upto the point.. could you look at mine answer..you will get better idea why its happening. Thanks :-)

Comment: I did edited mine answer, with little more detail..let me know if you don't understand anything.

Comment: I was saying your edit to my answer would be awesome ;)

Answer (score -1):

You need think in angular way.

Just rewrite your link function like this

```
var linker = function(scope, element, attrs) {
 element.html('<button ng-click="onClick()"  style="background:grey;">Button ' + scope.count + ' Clicked {{clicks}} times</button>');

 scope.clicks=0;
 scope.onClick = function(){
  scope.clicks+;
 }
 $compile(element.contents())(scope);
};
```

Comment: I don't think this is the solution. I understood what I was doing wrong. Every time I added a control, I was compiling the contents of it's parent all over again.

Comment: I think, you need think in `angular` way. Using `jQuery` in `angular` code is **bad** practice.